# ListAdapter "Error java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception

I can run my app on a emulator without a problem, but when I try to play it on a phone I get this error

> "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference".

I already tried setting the setContentView to (activity_main.xml), (content_main.xml), and I tried with both setContentViews and I keep getting the error. I'm also getting "EditText added is not a TextInputEditText" even though I already changed my EditText to a TextInputEditText.

MainActivity.java

```
package br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private MovieArrayAdapter movieArrayAdapter;
    private ListView movieListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
        movieListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.movieListView);
        movieArrayAdapter = new MovieArrayAdapter(this, movieList);
        movieListView.setAdapter(movieArrayAdapter);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TextInputEditText search_bar;
                search_bar = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
                URL url = createURL(search_bar.getText().toString());
                if(url != null){
                    dismissKeyboard(search_bar);
                    GetMovieTask getLocalMovieTask = new GetMovieTask();
                    getLocalMovieTask.execute(url);
                }else {
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout), R.string.invalid_url,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void dismissKeyboard (View view){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
    }

    private URL createURL (String movie){
        String apiKey = getString (R.string.api_key);
        String baseUrl = getString(R.string.nyt_url);
        try{
            String urlString = baseUrl + "?api_key=" + apiKey + "&query=" + URLEncoder.encode (movie, "UTF-8");
            return new URL(urlString);
        }
        catch( Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private class GetMovieTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, JSONObject> {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) params[0].openConnection();
                int response = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder ();
                    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))){
                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                            builder.append(line);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e){
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout), R.string.read_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout), R.string.connect_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                if (connection != null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject movie) {
            convertJSONToArrayList (movie);
            movieArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            movieListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
        }
    }

    private void convertJSONToArrayList (JSONObject forecast){
        movieList.clear();
        try{
            JSONArray results = forecast.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject movie = results.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject multimedia = movie.getJSONObject("multimedia");
                movieList.add(new Movie(movie.getString("display_title"),
                        movie.getString("publication_date"),
                        multimedia.getString("src")));

            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Movie.java

```
package br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Movie {
    public final String title;
    public final String publication_date;
    public final String iconURL;

    public Movie(String title,String publication_date, String iconName) {
        this.title = title;
        this.publication_date = publication_date;
        this.iconURL = iconName;
    }
}
```

MovieArrayAdapter.java

```
package br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MovieArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

    private static class ViewHolder{
        ImageView movieImage;
        TextView description;
        TextView publication_date;
    }

    private Map<String, Bitmap> bitmaps = new HashMap<>();
    public MovieArrayAdapter (Context context, List<Movie>
            forecast){
        super (context, -1, forecast);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Movie review = getItem (position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.complete_review, parent, false);
            viewHolder.movieImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.movieImage);
            viewHolder.description = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            viewHolder.publication_date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.publication_date);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        if (bitmaps.containsKey(review.iconURL)){
            viewHolder.movieImage.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(review.iconURL));
        }
        else{
            new LoadImageTask (viewHolder.movieImage).execute (review.iconURL);
        }

        Context context = getContext();
        viewHolder.description.setText(review.title);
        viewHolder.publication_date.setText(review.publication_date);
        return convertView;
    }

    private class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private ImageView imageView;
        public LoadImageTask (ImageView imageView){
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                try(InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream ()){
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    bitmaps.put (params[0], bitmap);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:elevation="@dimen/toolbar_elevation" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_magin_top"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:elevation="@dimen/rested_button_elevation"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/view">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/hint_text"
            android:elevation="@dimen/rested_search_elevation"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/movieListView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Error Message

```
07-28 21:18:00.812 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas E/Zygote: no v2
07-28 21:18:00.822 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-J110M_5.1.1 ver=48
07-28 21:18:00.822 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [1] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-J110M_5.1.1_0048
07-28 21:18:00.822 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
07-28 21:18:00.822 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
07-28 21:18:00.842 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas I/SAMP: ActivityThread() - SAMP_ENABLE : true
07-28 21:18:00.862 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: null for user  0
07-28 21:18:01.012 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: null for user  0
07-28 21:18:01.022 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/DisplayManager: DisplayManager()
07-28 21:18:01.022 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: null for user  0
07-28 21:18:01.092 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-28 21:18:01.172 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
07-28 21:18:01.172 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
07-28 21:18:01.362 5123-5138/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3506(700KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 27% free, 5MB/7MB, paused 7.831ms total 22.235ms
07-28 21:18:01.372 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
07-28 21:18:01.412 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-28 21:18:01.412 5123-5123/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas, PID: 5123
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2697)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2650)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200) 
07-28 21:29:10.422 8489-8489/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-28 21:29:10.522 8489-8489/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
07-28 21:29:10.522 8489-8489/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
07-28 21:29:10.612 8489-8489/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
07-28 21:29:10.612 8489-8489/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-28 21:29:10.612 8489-8489/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas, PID: 8489
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2697)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2650)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: i was just trying to help you with your formatting. yeah.

Comment: thx, first post here ^^

Comment: slow down sir, please change it back to activity_main and when the error comes please post that red things that show here.

Comment: edited post with error message, this message is the same for when the contentview is content_main.xml, activity_main.xml and when I use both content views

Comment: Your main activity code is not proper, as you are accessing view from different different xmls, list view is in content_main file, when floating and toolbar is in activity_main file so check that and first clean your code

Comment: thx for your answer, but i'm not sure to clean it, should I let the OnCreate handle the floating and toolbar, create a new function to access the listview and then call this function onCreate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I'm really dumb, since my project was for android 4.0 + and I was using elvation on my layout (which is only supported for 5.0 +), android studio made 2 different layouts, one for 5.0 - and one for 5.0 + and for some reason the layour for 5.0+ did not have the ListView on it. I just added the ListView on v21/content_main and it worked!

Thx for everyone's help and sorry for the dumb mistake with poor explanation

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `setContentView(arg0)` twice, which probably isn't helping.

Comment: I was trying something out when I did that, but it did not work with one      'setContentView(arg0)' also

Comment: You need to call findViewById() after setContentView(), so make sure you removed the right one.